# How can I create a query, which includes all tasks related to a specific user story?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, workitem, azure-boards, wiql

I am trying to create a query in Azure DevOps, which only gives me the tasks of a specific feature or epic.
If I have Feature A, Feature B and Feature C, I only want the tasks related to Feature B.
Which field/operator in the query editor do I need to use?

Answer (score 3):

You can query linked work items in the following two ways depending on how you have them defined:

- Query to return hierarchically (parent-child) linked work items
- Query to return non-hierarchically (related, direct) linked work items

From your description, it looks like your work items are non-hierarchically linked.
So you can use the Use the **Work items and Direct links query** and specify the filter criteria for both top and linked work items, and select the types of links used to filter the dependencies.

For example:
[image: Example]

To learn more about the types of links, check this article: [Use direct links to view dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies).

Additional reading:

- [Query types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/about-managed-queries?view=azure-devops#query-types-flat-direct-links-tree)
- [Query for linked work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/work-item-links?view=azure-devops)